# Unable to change gid of a process

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

I need to change the PGID of my parent process, so I did something like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define KIDS 10

int main()
{
    struct timespec a = {10, 0};
    int pid;
    int* pids = (int*) calloc(KIDS, sizeof(int));
    int argument = 0;
    int procNumber;

    for (procNumber = 0; procNumber < KIDS; procNumber++) {
        pid = fork();
        argument = procNumber;
        if (pid == 0)
            break;
        pids[procNumber] = pid;
    }

    if (pid == 0) {  
        // child stuff
    } else {
        printf("My group: %d\n", getpgrp());
        if (setpgid(0, 6654) == -1)
            perror("setpgid() error:");
        printf("My new group: %d\n", getpgrp());
    }

    nanosleep(&a,NULL);
    free(pids);

    return 0;
}
```

And I get `Operation not permitted` error.

What should I do to avoid this error and change groupid of the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(setpgid(0,6654)==-1)
    perror("setpgid() error:");
```

I think the error means " An attempt was made to move a process into a process group in a different session"

So:

```
[root@localhost test_c]# sleep 10000 &
[2] 2922
```

I start a new process which pid is 2922 in my terminal，which means it's process group id also be 2922.

Then i change you source code `if(setpgid(0,6654)==-1)` to `if(setpgid(0,2922)==-1)`, things works.

Comment: But in man I read:
 "setpgid() sets the PGID of the process specified by pid to pgid.  If
       pid is zero, then the process ID of the calling process is used."

Comment: Is there any way to do it automatically? I mean when i create  process sleep using popen it has got the same GPID. Is there any sollution?

Answer (score 2):

The `Operation not permitted` error message is associated with the `EPERM` error code, which according to [`man 2 setpgid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpgid.2.html) (quoting):

> EPERM
>
> An attempt was made to move a process into a process group in
>   a different session, or to change the process group ID of one
>   of the children of the calling process and the child was in a
>   different session, or to change the process group ID of a
>   session leader (setpgid(), setpgrp()).

So, it seems like there are 3 different explanations for the error you receive:

1. You're trying to move a process into a process group in a different session.
2. You're trying to change the PGID of a child which is in a different session.
3. You're trying to change the PGID of a session leader.

Cases 2 and 3 look irrelevant to your problem, so my guess would be that you're in the first case. If `6654` is randomly selected, it could be that process group 6654 is in a different session.

You can verify this running something like `$ ps eajx` and checking the `SID` field of the output for each of the processes involved, including the process group 6654.